# Данные из JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Можно ли чисто на клиенте(то есть в браузере) не трогая серверную часть с помощью javascript сохранить данные в файл или в другое хранилище. 
Например: у меня есть сайт и я дожен авторизоваться. 
Вот при клике войти мой javascript код должен сохранить логин и пароль в текстовый файл. Я не имею доступ к серверу и не могу там на index.php (или на другом файле) написать это. Этот скрипт должен работать только на браузере моего компа. Можно ли это сделать? Если можно, то как это сделать?

Comment: Стремная тема... Сохраняйте в local storage что ли...

Comment: Это как? можете подробно описать.

Comment: @Итачи https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=localStorage

Comment: Не вздумайте хранить пароли в чистом виде в браузере. Так делать опасно даже когда вы храните их на удалённом сервере! Пользуйтесь хешированием паролей.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, [`local storage`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) подходит лучше всего для хранения данных на клиентской стороне.

Засетать данные:

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

Получить:

```
var value = localStorage.getItem("key"); // value = "value"
```

Большинство браузеров поддерживают `local storage` (вплоть до IE8).

Для просмотра текущих значений можно воспользоваться DevTools (`F12`) Chrome браузера, перейдя по `Application` > `Local Storage`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я вот хочу спросить чтобы использовать local storage я должен ли иметь доступ к серверу?

Comment: @Итачи нет, не должны. "local" в данном случае относится к клиенту

Comment: А я куда должен этот код записать на сам браузер или куда?

Comment: @Итачи выучите хотя бы основы JavaScript.

Comment: Как вывести все айтемы(getitem) в local storage. Или лучше сказать как распечатать массив(обьект) local storage. Все данные в local storage. Работаю с jquery.

Comment: @Итачи зачем вам это делать? Как посмотреть сохраненные данные я написал в ответе дополнительно